# CSS classes within classes

Tags: css, image

I have a page where I'm trying to use a lot of CSS.
I have a main wrapper class with background and everything and then a content class within that. Within the content class I then have IDs for various articles.
Within some of these articles I'd like images aligned to the right, but I don't seem to be able to do this.
From what I know

```
<div class="article">           
    In 1904, Sunderland's management was embroiled in a payment scandaat he would repay the money after his benthe money, claiming it had been a gift. An investigation conducted by the as part of a "re-signing/win/draw bonus", which violated the Association's rules. Sunderland were fined £250 (£20 thousand today), and six directors were suspended for two and a half years for not showing a true record of the club's
    <div class="picha">
            <img src="image/test.png">
    </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

should apply picha (i.e. align right, set a border) to the image...but it doesn't.

How is this handled?
Or better yet is there a way to set rules for images within a  ID that isn't specifically for images? i.e. text is handled one way but all images posted in that id get special treatment.

edit- so updated attempt:
css has:

```
div.article {

    border: solid;
    background-color:red;
    }

div.article img{ 
    border: 10px solid #f1f1f1;
    float: right;
    }
```

and page has:

```
 <div class="article"> 
 <a name="article1">
             random text
        <img src="image/test.png">
</a>
</div>
```

The image shows and alligns right but is below the text and outside the text's box, I'd like it quite neatly inside the article box but to the right.
If I add float left to the text then the article box stretches but the image remains below the text.

edit2- and I'm a stupid newbie. Had to have the image before the text. Done!

Comment: You have a stray `</a>` btw.

Comment: no offense but why dont you add a class to the image itself? isnt that much easyer? `<img class="picha" src="image/test.png"`

**CSS**

`.picha{
border: 1px solid #333;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use?:

```
div.article {
    // This applies to all content
}

div.article img {
    // This applies to the image
}

div.article span {
    // This applies to everything inside a span
}
```

You could write your text inside a span like this:

```
<div class='article'>
    <img src='' />
    <span>My text</span>
</div>
```

This way you don't need a wrapping `div` for you `image`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access this nested div, you can either do as @Aquillo said.

Or do this:

```
.article .picha
{
 /*Your css*/

}
```

and

```
.article .picha img
{
 /*Your img css*/

}
```